# Does the DropDownList selected property ever change in html?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html.dropdownlistfor

I am using mvc3 and have a dropdownlist (using DropDownListFor helper). I set the selected value to my default value. When the user selects a different item, the selected property of that item is not marked as such, i.e. the default value still has the selected property in the rendered html. Is this normal behaviour? If i use jquery and get the ddl val property it is correctly set to the recently selected item...is this just how dropdownlists work? I've checked IE, FF, Chrome and IE doesnt even have a selected property next to the options...

Answer (score 1):

Edit:
Infact ive just tested it with firefox 9 + . It does change the html source with the selected changing place.

```
<option selected="selected" value="2">(0002)    </option>
<option value="3">(0003)     </option>
```

Ensure you are viewing the source of the current(correct) page, and the correct option list. `Control + U` in Firefox or Chrome.

As you change the dropdownbox, behind the scenes the selected value will have changed. As you have observed. And so submitting etc will use the new selected value.

So its nothing to worry about anyway :)

Comment: Thanks! I'm inspecting the ddl using firebug, i would've thought it would show changes? seem to remember that happening for some reason previously...

Comment: Ive just checked Chrome and firefox, and they both do it. I remembered it not being the case in firefox. Make sure you are viewing the source of the correct page. `Cntrl + U` in Chrome or Firefox.